# Posting Integer array in postgress through Postman on spring boot JPA service

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, postman

I am trying to post the below request through postman in the item table to a spring boot service . I am using JPA ,  Postgress , Spring boot .

{
"allGroups" : [1,2,3],
"assetName" : "testname"
}

The Entity class is like below for the Asset table

public class Asset implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String assetName;
@Type(type = "int-array")
@Column(name = "all_groups")
private Integer[] allGroups;
}
```

And the corresponding DTO is

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class AssetDto {
private long serialVersionUID;
@Max(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 255)
@NotBlank(message = "assetName may not be empty")
private String assetName;
private Integer[] allGroups;
}
```

When i am posting it is saving the "assetName" property but not the "allGroups" array . How to make it work submit array also .

Comment: `@Column(name = "asset_name") private Integer[] allGroups;` you sure this is correct?

Comment: sorry typo mistake , i have corrected .